# “rather than” vs “as opposed to”

Tags: differences, expressions

> We do not know whether X will have an effect on element Y as opposed to others.
>   We do not know whether X will have an effect on element Y rather than on others.

The first version is the first one I wrote, but it doesn't convince me at all. The second one should be more correct, but it doesn't sound too natural.  Is one preferred over the other?

Is there another way to express the same thing?

Comment: General Reference. They're both perfectly valid, and it would be hair-splitting to claim any difference in meaning. Use whichever you like, as a stylistic choice.

Comment: To me they do not seem to mean the same thing. They are both grammatically correct, though. The choice, therefore, depends on what really you want to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the second one, because I might not know in the first one if you mean *X (as opposed to others)* or *Y as opposed to **on** others*.

Alternatively,

> `"We do not know whether X will have an effect on element Y or on other elements"`

Answer (score 0):

I think **rather than**  shows the preference of one over the other and in case of **as opposed to**  , it's saying **opposite to something**. Although both are being used for comparison But you can feel the difference.